# How to restore database schema using DDLgen utility

Tags: command-line, ddl, sap-ase

I am using the `ddlgen` tool to get DDLs or whole databases. Now I need to re-generate databases into another location (structure only).

Can anyone help me to re-create database schema in another location?

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote/accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 1):

`ddlgen` creates sql scripts

To recreate your database structure, just run the scripts in the correct order against your new system.

```
isql -Uusername -Sservername -iDDLGenScript.sql
```

If you have multiple scripts, then this is the recommended order from the [SAP ASE Documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_ase160/helpdata/en/a7/ed349ebc2b1014b50fbd20d6921128/content.htm?frameset=/en/a5/ff340bbc2b10149ec1e78867c902f1/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/a5/ff340bbc2b10149ec1e78867c902f1/plain.htm&node_id=30&show_children=false)

> 1. Segment
> 2. Group
> 3. User
> 4. Rules
> 5. Defaults
> 6. UDDs
> 7. Encrypted Keys
> 8. User Tables
> 9. Proxy Tables
> 10. Triggers
> 11. Functions and Views
>
>     1. All functions without any dependency
>     2. All views without any dependency
>     3. All functions and all views with any dependency on any objects
> 12. Instead of trigger
> 13. Stored Procedures
> 14. Extended Stored Procedures
> 15. PRS
> 16. User Defined Web Services